# setTimeout related methods in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a slideshow:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
    <img src="abc2.jpg">
    <img src="abc3.jpg">
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function asd(){
    $('.fadein :first-child').appendTo('.fadein');
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').appendTo('.fadein').hide().fadeIn().end();
    }, 1000);
});
```

I'd like to have a setTimeout method which affects the setInterval method above and if its possible, the clearInterval method being called when this div - ".fadein" is clicked.

Here is what I tried with so many mistakes that you can't even imagine:

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/C3f6J/32/

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  I don't understand.

Comment: I tried to make a setTimeout method which has a delay of 5000 mseconds before the slideshow starts

Comment: You appear to be using some of the jQuery methods like `.end()` incorrectly. Please spend more time reading the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), especially the parts about [`complete` callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

Comment: @ArchevildaHunter: And what do you want this `setTimeout` to do?

Comment: there's a scope issue

Comment: You want to delay the function `asd()`?

Comment: yes with a timeout of 5 seconds

Comment: `setTimeout('asd()', 5000)'` doesn't work in your document ready section?

Comment: Then just do: `$(function(){ setTimeout(function asd(//...){}, 5000); });`?

Comment: @Robb: You're supposed to pass a function, not a string, to `setTimeout`.  (You *can* pass a string, but it's bad practice).  P.S. This *is* his `document.ready` section.

Comment: Well I tried but didn't appear to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/C3f6J/35/

Comment: @ArchevildaHunter: That's because `$(function asd(){});` is the same as `$(document).ready(function asd(){});`.  It's running it on ready.  Declare the function on its own (just `function asd(){}`), then do `$(function(){ setTimeout(asd, 5000); });`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it didn't work. Is it because asd() function contains setInterval method? Fiddle of the attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/C3f6J/38/

Comment: @ArchevildaHunter: Check your console.  You have a syntax error.  It should be `function asd(){}` not `function asd(){});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this code:

```
var myVar;
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').appendTo('.fadein');
        myVar = setInterval(function () {
            $('.fadein :first-child').appendTo('.fadein').hide().fadeIn().end();
        }, 1000);
    }, 5000);
    $('.fadein').on('click', function () {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    });
});
```

`myVar` contains the interval reference and its globally scoped and it's starts after a timeout of 5 seconds, if you click `fadein` the interval is cleared.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VVSuN/